# Adding the output of one graph to another graph

Tags: python, contour

I would like to find a way to translate and add the bottom graph (from y = -20 to 0) onto the above graph (from y = 0-20) so that the final domain is between y = 0 to 20:

[image]

However, I am finding problems doing it, as the graph I used to draw the bottom graph (R12) has already a negative input, thus it will not show up on the positive y-axis. Here is my code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 1001
lower = 0
upper = 20
u = np.linspace(lower, upper, N)
t1a, t3a = np.meshgrid(u,-u)
t1, t3 = np.meshgrid(u,u)
omega = 10
delta = 5
tau = 2
mu = 1
t2 = 0.1


def g(t):
    return delta * (omega ** 2) * (tau ** 2) * ((np.e ** (-t/tau))+(t/tau)-1)


R12 = 1 * (mu ** 4) * (np.e **(-1j * omega * (t3a-(t1a)))) * (np.e ** (-g(t1a)+g(t2)-g(t3a)-g(t1a+t2)-g(t2+t3a)+g(t1a+t2+t3a)))
R45 = 1 * (mu ** 4) * (np.e ** (-1j * omega * (t3+t1))) * (np.e ** (-g(t1)-g(t2)-g(t3)+g(t1+t2)+g(t2+t3)-g(t1+t2+t3)))
R12_fft = np.fft.fftshift((np.fft.fft2((R12)))) / np.sqrt(len(R12)) 
R45_fft = np.fft.fftshift((np.fft.fft2((R45)))) / np.sqrt(len(R45))
R_pure = (R12_fft + R45_fft)

plt.contourf(t1a,t3a,R12_fft, cmap = 'seismic')
plt.contourf(t1,t3,R45_fft, cmap = 'seismic')
plt.xlabel('${\omega}_{3}$', fontsize = 24)
plt.ylabel('${\omega}_{1}$', fontsize = 24)
plt.xlim(-20, 20)
plt.ylim(-20, 20)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

As an example, if I try to do the simple adding:

```
plt.contourf(t1,t3,R_pure, cmap = 'seismic')
```

[image]

it basically gives me back the same shape of the graph. What I would like instead is superimposing the bottom graph onto the top and adding the output together. Is there any way I can achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that isn't the sum of the two graphs?  I'm just looking at the range on the colorbar. (you could test it with two shapes which aren't the same)

Comment: @Steve It is the sum but it's not the correct one as the bottom graph has just been reflected about the x-axis and added with the top graph, what I would like is the addition of the top graph when the bottom graph is "cut" and brought on top of it. Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: To clarify, currently your bottom graph is reflected about `y=0`, but you want it translated by `y = y+20`?

Comment: @Steve Yes, and I would like to add that graph to the above graph.

Comment: Instead of `R_pure = (R12_fft + R45_fft)` could you flip `R45_fft` as `R45_fft[::-1,:]` (or perhaps it'd be `R45_fft[:, ::-1]`) and add that instead?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like it's a bit too dumb, so it's probably wrong.

```
R_pure = (R12_fft + abs(R45_fft))
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm I think so, could I ask how did you achieve this?

Comment: @LinusChoy See edit. + I adapted the scale of the plot.